# In Haskell, is there a built-in function that creates a list of one element?

Tags: list, haskell

Looking for a built-in function that will do the following:

```
mklist x = [x]
```

The benefit is that I can use it in a composition to create a list of one element. Understand that (replicate 1) is available but is there a more direct function? Would be useful in situations like this:

```
["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"] >>= mklist . ("Hello " ++)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Monadic [return](http://www.haskell.org/all_about_monads/html/listmonad.html):

```
return x
```

Or:

```
(:[]) x
```

It's less characters, but more shift-key usage, so might be harder to type.

Comment: :-) Of course your example could just as easily be done using `map`, but I'm assuming your real scenario is more complex.

Comment: `pure` from Control.Applicative also works. That's four non-shifted letters! As with `return` any type errors may get more complicated, though.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame `pure` isn't in the Prelude, though. But if you do have Control.Applicative imported anyway, then `pure` is nice and short, just like we Haskell programmers like.

Comment: Ooh, monadic `return`.  +1 for sneakiness and code obfuscation!